# socks5 proxy client with context support

Tags: go, proxy

Is it possible to use a context with the `Dialer` returned by the `SOCKS5` function from net/proxy library?

If a SOCKS5 proxy `Dialer` blocks while establishing the connection, an HTTP client using the proxy `Dialer` could get stuck without a way to abort the connection.

Comment: Have you tried casting the `Dialer` returned by the `SOCKS5` function to a `ContextDialer`?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood of `golang.org/x/net/proxy.SOCKS5` it uses `golang.org/x/net/internal/socks.Dialer`, which has an exported method `DialContext`, and since Go 1.7, `http.Transport` supports a custom `DialContext` as a field. So you can cast the dialer to an interface with method `DialContext` and set it to a custom transport.

```
dc := dialer.(interface {
    DialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)
})
httpTransport.DialContext = dc.DialContext
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tSi9IZ-2Zqg

Note: while this is valid Go code, some would argue it relies on implementation details that the package does not want to export (hidden in `internal`). I think it is best to send an issue to Go team to ask for export it; if it is too much an issue for you, you can either copy the code and preserve it from changing, or use `http.Client.Timeout` or write start every `http.Do` concurrently and wraps a `select` over it for context like dealing with any blocking operation.